# How to retrieve form constraint violations messages with profiler in Symfony 6 unit test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony6

I'm trying to unit tests some potential behaviors on a contact form in Symfony 6, and specifically test the messages returned by the constraints on the form fields.

To do so I try to get these messages within the profiler, but I can't find any method to retrieve the error messages returned, all I found is how to get the number of errors :

```
 public function testFailureEmailSending()
{
    // Given
    $this->client->enableProfiler();

    // When
    $this->client->request('POST', '/contact', [
        'contact' => [
            'name' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'phone' => '',
            'message' => 'Less than 30 characters !',
        ]]);

    if ($profile = $this->client->getProfile()) {
        $validator = $profile->getCollector('validator');
        $violationsCount = $validator->getViolationsCount();
        // how to retrieve error messages ?
    }

    // Then
    $this->assertEquals(4, $violationsCount); // works
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to get to the constraint violations via the profiler. You might want to write a proper unit test just for the validation, without the whole request-controller-overhead. Symfony provides a ValidatorBuilder, you can use in a unit test quite easily:

```php
public function testFailureEmailSending(): void
{
    $validator = Validation::createValidationBuilder()
        ->enableAnnotationMapping()
        ->getValidator();

    $violations = $validator->validate($contact);

    // Perform assertions
}
```

That being said, the collector provides a method `getCalls()` which returns the collected data from the validator. The TraceableValidator used by the DataCollector will add the collected data whenever validate is called, as you can see in [TraceableValidator.php#L97-101](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v6.1.4/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/TraceableValidator.php#L97-L101).

In other words, you should be able to retrieve the violations by doing:

```php
// Be careful, this is not the actual array, but a Data-object from the VarDumper component, but it provides array access
$collectedData = $profile->getCollector('validator')->getCalls();
// You might need to call iterator_to_array() first for the next line to work
$violations = end($collectedData)['violations'];
```